# c#/Access 2010 - DoCmd.OutputTo error running from task scheduler

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-access-2010

I have a c# console application running daily as a scheduled task.

Recently I've added a new functionality to send an e-mail with an attached pdf report, using Access 2010 built-in pdf export:

```
using MsAccess = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;
//(...)
AccApp = new MsAccess.Application();
AccApp.Visible = false;
AccApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(DBPathname, false);
AccApp.DoCmd.OutputTo(MsAccess.AcOutputObjectType.acOutputReport, "GMB_CSS_Report", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", ReportFilename, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, MsAccess.AcExportQuality.acExportQualityPrint);
//(...)
```

When I run the new version interactively on the command line it works well, exporting the report as a PDF to the designated path\file.

But when I run it from task manager, **using the same credentials**, it crashes on the DoCmd.OutputTo(...) statement with the error:

*(System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException) Microsoft Access can't save the output data to the file you've selected.*

That does not make any sense, as the application successfuly writes several other files to the same folder, running either from the console or from the task manager.

I've also found that the application runs without the error as a scheduled task on a third PC, not integrated in the company AD domain (the production and dev hosts are on the domain), even though all 3 hosts have the same s/w level (Win7 SP1, Access 2010 updated to latest patches via Windows Update).

This is bizarre... am I missing something here ? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got the same problem. Have you find the cause or a workaround in the meantime?

Comment: Nope, I gave up and used PDFCreator COM integration instead

Comment: Did you use PDFCreator with C# and Access Interop, or only PDFCreator with C#? In other works: do you manage in creating report at runtime with access interop substituting docmd.outputto with PDFCreator or not?

Comment: I used PDFCreator to save the pdf report using DoCmd.PrintOut via a PDFCreator printer, as an OutputTo replacement. It works well in both interactive and scheduled modes. Major drawbacks are the added complexity - about 30 more lines of c# source to handle the PDFCreator object model - and an additional dependency on the processing host, PDFCreator itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is in the "PDFFormat(*.pdf)" constant string.

The right one for PDF is this:

```
    public const string acFormatPDF = "PDF Format (*.pdf)";
```

And this is for RTF:

```
    public const string acFormatRTF = "Rich Text Format (*.rtf)";
```

I still have got problems with the same function on a 64Bit version of Access 2010 running on Windows 2008 Server 64Bit, while it works perfectly on a Windows Server 2003 machine 32bit with Access 2010 32bit.

Comment: The program works well in the command prompt, so I guess the spaces must be removed when the string is parsed internally, otherwise it would not run at all. But your strings do seem the correct ones.